# Troubles with the if and else statement

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement

I am still a beginner in C and am currently having trouble with if and else statements.

I kept getting an element in the array deleted despite the input not being found in that array.

The output:

```
Before deletion:
B D Z X W M O S P H G E 
Input your letter to delete: 
A

Letter to delete: A


Element A is not found in the array


Array Content:
B D Z X W M O S P H G
```

Instead of the desired output

```
Before deletion:
B D Z X W M O S P H G E 
Input your letter to delete: 
A

Letter to delete: A


Element A is not found in the array


Array Content:
B D Z X W M O S P H G E
```

I have tried to change `for (i = 0; i < size-1; i++)` into `for (i = 0; i < size; i++)` in `else` statement but the `printf` would only show the original array. I also tried to construct `printf` for the original array but both the original array and the misleading array content will print in the output. I need to know how to handle the error. Please teach me how.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
{
    char letters[] = {'B','D','Z','X','W','M','O','S','P','H','G','E'};
    char toDelete, found;
    int size = 12, i, pos, ch;


    printf("Before deletion:\n");
        for (int i = 0;i<size;i++)  {
            printf("%c ", letters[i]);
    }
    printf("\nInput your letter to delete: \n");
        scanf(" %c", &toDelete);

    found=0;

    printf("\nLetter to delete: %c\n", toDelete);
        for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
          if(letters[i] == toDelete)
        {
            found = 1;
            pos = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found == 1) {

        for(i = pos; i < size-1; i++)
            letters[i] = letters[i+1];
            
    }
    else
        printf("\n\nElement %c is not found in the array\n\n", toDelete);

    printf("\nArray Content:\n");

    for(i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
        printf("%c ", letters[i]);

}
    return;
}
```

I have taken into account David's advice. Here is my previous attempt. It worked.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
{
    char letters[12] = {"BDZXWMOSPHGE"};
    char toDelete, found;
    int i, pos, ch;


    printf("Before deletion:\n");
        for (int i = 0;i<12;i++)  {
            printf("%c ", letters[i]);
    }
    printf("\nInput your letter to delete: \n");
        scanf(" %c", &toDelete);

    found=0;

    printf("\nLetter to delete: %c\n", toDelete);
        for (i=0; i < 12; i++) {
          if(letters[i] == toDelete)
        {
            found = 1;
            pos = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found == 1) {

        for(i = pos; i < 12; i++)
            letters[i] = letters[i+1];
            
    }
    else
        printf("\n\nElement %c is not found in the array\n\n", toDelete);

    printf("\nArray Content:\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        printf("%c ", letters[i]);

}
    return;
}
```

You have my gratitude. Feel free to leave tips on how to improve this even more.

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < size-1; i++)` The final loop always prints `size-1`  characters, but if no character was found and removed then it should print all `size` characters in the original array.

Comment: If you remove a character, then you need to decrement `size`. Whether a character has been removed or not your output loop at the end should be `for(i = 0; i < size; ..` You can also initialize `letters` as `char letters[12] = "BDZXWMOSPHGE";`  (less typing, the 12 ensures no nul-terminating character. Without the `12` or with a number greater than `12` it would be)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few additional tips. First, don't use *Magic-Numbers* in the body of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NCHR   12       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main() {

    char letters[NCHR] = "BDZXWMOSPHGE", toDelete;
    int pos = -1, size = NCHR;                      /* pos & found serve same purpose */
```

(**note:** `char letters[NCHR] = "BDZXWMOSPHGE"` is a complete initializer itself, there isn't a need to wrap the quoted characters in braces.)

Not an error, but think about limiting the variables you use to just what is needed and no more. Since you have declared `pos` as an `int`, simply initializing to `-1` can indicate no letter was found, otherwise `pos = i;` indicates the letter was found.

Also not an error, but there is no need to call the *variadic* `printf()` function when there are no conversions to be made in the output. `puts()` is fine for outputting a string and will append the `'\n'` character to the output. If you need *end-of-line* control and don't want the `'\n'` appended, then `fputs()` is fine. (note: a good compiler will make the change (optimization) for you), e.g.

```
    puts ("Before deletion:");                      /* no converstion, just use puts */
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)                  /* i can be local to loop */
        printf (i ? " %c" : "%c", letters[i]);      /* ternary controls space */
    
    fputs ("\n\nInput your letter to delete: ", stdout);    /* fputs is fine */
```

(**note:** the use of the *ternary* to control whether a leading space is output. You generally do not want to include whitespace at the end of your output -- other than a `'\n'` character)

**Most Important Tip**

Validate EVERY user-input, and if converting digits to a number, validate EVERY conversion by **checking the return** of the input or conversion function used. Even with `scanf (" %c", &toDelete)` the user can generate a manual `EOF` canceling input using a <kbd>Ctrl + d</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl + z</kbd> on windows.

If you don't catch `EOF` and blindly use the variable (that now holds an indeterminate value), you invoke *Undefined Behavior* and the defined operation of your code is over. (it can do anything from appearing to run correctly or SegFault). All you need is:

```
    if (scanf (" %c", &toDelete) != 1) {            /* always validate EVERY input */
        puts ("(user canceled input)");             /* manual EOF is valid input */
        return 0;                                   /* Ctrl+d, Ctrl+z on windows */
    }
    printf ("\nLetter to delete: %c\n", toDelete);  /* now printf is needed */
```

Now iterate check whether the character input matches any of the characters in the array:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)                  /* iterate looking for letter */
        if (letters[i] == toDelete) {
            pos = i;                                /* pos serves as found flag */
            break;
        }
```

(**note:** only if the character given matches a letter in the array is `pos` updated to hold the index where the letter was found)

If the letter was not found, no need to output the array a second time unchanged (not really any need, no changes were made), e.g.

```
    if (pos == -1) {    /* if pos not set, output not found and return */
        fprintf (stderr, "\nLetter not found '%c'.\n", toDelete);
        return 0;
    }
```

There is no need for an `else`, you simply end the program by returning from `main()`. If the character was found, then iterating from the index following `pos` and assigning the current element to the prior element eliminates having to change to `size - 1` in your loop declaration. Looping consistently from `0 <= i < size` is a good way to avoid an *off-by-one* error that attempts to access the element one-after the end of your array...

```
    for (int i = pos + 1; i < size; i++)    /* iterate pos+1 to end, no change to size */
        letters[i-1] = letters[i];          /* assign current to previous */
    size -= 1;                              /* decrement size */
```

Only after the element has been removed do you decrement the value in `size`. Now, again, there is no change to the loop declaration needed to output the contents of the array after the elements is removed, e.g.

```
    puts ("\nArray Content:");                      /* puts is fine */
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)                  /* no change in loop declaration */
        printf (i ? " %c" : "%c", letters[i]);      /* same ternary trick */
    putchar ('\n');                                 /* tidy up with newline */
```

(**note:** always make sure the final output from your program ends with a `'\n'`. Not only does this make the operation of your program POSIX compliant, more importantly, it prevents your program from screwing up my next command-line prompt by causing it to appear somewhere in the middle of the terminal after your last output `:)`

Since C99, the return from `main()` is `0` by default, so unless you are returning something else, there isn't a requirement to include `return 0;` at the end of your program. But note there are still some compilers out there that are 21 years+ behind the times and do not comply with the C99 standard (cough.... Windows 7 Development Toolkit containing VS10...)

Putting it altogether you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NCHR   12       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main() {

    char letters[NCHR] = "BDZXWMOSPHGE", toDelete;
    int pos = -1, size = NCHR;                      /* pos & found serve same purpose */

    puts ("Before deletion:");                      /* no converstion, just use puts */
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)                  /* i can be local to loop */
        printf (i ? " %c" : "%c", letters[i]);      /* ternary controls space */
    
    fputs ("\n\nInput your letter to delete: ", stdout);    /* fputs is fine */
    if (scanf (" %c", &toDelete) != 1) {            /* always validate EVERY input */
        puts ("(user canceled input)");             /* manual EOF is valid input */
        return 0;                                   /* Ctrl+d, Ctrl+z on windows */
    }
    printf ("\nLetter to delete: %c\n", toDelete);  /* now printf is needed */
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)                  /* iterate looking for letter */
        if (letters[i] == toDelete) {
            pos = i;                                /* pos serves as found flag */
            break;
        }
    
    if (pos == -1) {    /* if pos not set, output not found and return */
        fprintf (stderr, "\nLetter not found '%c'.\n", toDelete);
        return 0;
    }
    
    for (int i = pos + 1; i < size; i++)    /* iterate pos+1 to end, no change to size */
        letters[i-1] = letters[i];          /* assign current to previous */
    size -= 1;                              /* decrement size */
    
    puts ("\nArray Content:");                      /* puts is fine */
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)                  /* no change in loop declaration */
        printf (i ? " %c" : "%c", letters[i]);      /* same ternary trick */
    putchar ('\n');                                 /* tidy up with newline */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

First:

```
$ ./bin/arr_del_char
Before deletion:
B D Z X W M O S P H G E

Input your letter to delete: B

Letter to delete: B

Array Content:
D Z X W M O S P H G E
```

Not Found:

```
$ ./bin/arr_del_char
Before deletion:
B D Z X W M O S P H G E

Input your letter to delete: C

Letter to delete: C

Letter not found 'C'.
```

Element in Middle:

```
$ ./bin/arr_del_char
Before deletion:
B D Z X W M O S P H G E

Input your letter to delete: S

Letter to delete: S

Array Content:
B D Z X W M O P H G E
```

Last Element:

```
$ ./bin/arr_del_char
Before deletion:
B D Z X W M O S P H G E

Input your letter to delete: E

Letter to delete: E

Array Content:
B D Z X W M O S P H G
```

User Cancels Input:

```
$ ./bin/arr_del_char
Before deletion:
B D Z X W M O S P H G E

Input your letter to delete: (user canceled input)
```

On balance, you did a pretty good job with your code. The changes above (other than the **Most Important Tip**) are largely just that Tips on ways you can look at what you are doing differently. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.